# Clustering Suggestion for highly imbalanced medical data with binary and numerical variables

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, binary-data, similarities, hierarchical-clustering

I have a highly imbalanced medical data set with approx 4k binary cohorts(variables) and 100 numerical variables. I want to separate patients into different clusters based on similarity. I tried using SVD(Singular Value Decomposition) for dimensionality reduction and then applying dbscan. But, it doesn't seems to work good.
So, what else can I use to deal with such data for clustering similar patients based on variables into one cluster?